# Progressive Web App

Tags: plugin-development, performance

Is there any way to think about building a site as a Progressive Web App when using Craft CMS? Any steps / plugins that can help build a site as a PWA to enable features like Add to Homescreen, Offline reading support, push notifications?

**PWA Overview**
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-progressive-web-app/?hl=en

**Wordpress to PWA**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565068/converting-wordpress-website-to-progressive-web-app

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would think that most of these features would be custom files that live alongside your CraftCMS build to enable PWA functionality.

You'd need a manifest.json file and some service worker js files to get it working; the PWA functionality would really be an add-on to the CraftCMS functionality and does not need to be connected, so I don't think you'd need a CraftCMS plugin.

Good luck!